# What is the difference between UD and UCD?

Tags: user-centered-design, design-principles

Is [Universal Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_design) the same as [User-Centered Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-centered_design) or are they different principles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Universal design tries to plan and manufacture products (environments, buildings, furniture, etc.) that *can be used by everybody*, regardless of their age, gender or possible disabilities. Usually UD is used in context of physical objects, not software.

User-centered design is a user interface design method that focuses the needs, goals and limitations of end users - in contrast of e.g. a features-first designed UI.

Albeit, if we extend the methods to software, they are not exactly the same, but share some characteristicts. I'd say that UD is a subset of UCD. Usually, a big part of UCD is the participation of the actual users (in form of either cooperative, participatory or contextual design), not necessarily a part of UD.

Answer (score 0):

"Universal design" or "Design for all" is a design metodology focused on inclusion of all user, expecially users that has different mobility o perception. UD aims to make barrier-free products.

UCD instead is a design metodology where the user behavior and their characteristics are pointed as the main factors.

UD is UCD, but UCD is not always UD.